# How to update ID column in table 1 from table 2 using Type in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, sql-update, inner-join

So as an example here is table 1

```
      ID       Type        Description
------------ ------------ --------------
       5          A          abc 
       6          B          xyz 
       7          C          rst
       8          D          lne
```

This is table 2:

```
      JID       Type     TDescription
------------ ------------ --------------
       1          A          123 
       2          B          456 
       3          C          789
       4          D          357
```

So I want to update table 1 but just ID column using table 2  by matching their Type.

Expected updated Table:

```
      ID       Type        Description
------------ ------------ --------------
       1          A          abc 
       2          B          xyz 
       3          C          rst
       4          D          lne
```

I'm not sure how to update a table's single column using another table's column to match the rows.

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server? Please tag only one database. The syntax of update statements is generally database-dependent.

Answer (score 1):

One option uses a subquery:

```
update table1
set id = (select t2.jid from table2 t2 where t2.type = table1.id)
```

This syntax should work in both MySQL and SQL Server.

Note, however, that it will set to `null` `id`s of `table1` whose `type` does not exists in `table2`. If you want to avoid that, it is simpler to use the update/join syntax.

In MySQL:

```
update table1 t1
inner join table2 t2 on t2.type = t1.type
set t1.id = t2.jid
```

In SQL Server:

```
update t1
set t1.id = t2.jid
from table1 t1
inner join table2 t2 on t2.type = t1.type
```